# Labeling a matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, jupyter-notebook

I've been trying to do a code that labels a binary matrix, i.e. I want to do a function that finds all connected components in an image and assigns a unique label to all points in the same component. The problem is that I found a function, imbinarize(), that creates a binary image and I want to know how to do it without that function (because I don't know how to do it).

EDIT: I realized that it isn't needed to binarize the image, because it is being assumed that all the images that are put as argument are already binarized. So, I changed my code. It happens that code is not working, and I think the problem is in one of the cycles, but I can't understand why.

```
   import numpy as np
   %matplotlib inline
   from matplotlib import pyplot as plt



   def connected_components(image):
   M = image * 1
   # write your code here

   (row, column) = M.shape #shape of the matrix

   #Second step
   L = 2

   #Third step
   q = []

   #Fourth step
   #Method to look for ones starting on the pixel (0, 0) and going from left to right and top-down

   for i in np.arange(row):
      for j in np.arange(column):
          if M[i][j] == 1:
            M[i][j] = L
            q.append(M[i-1][j])
            q.append(M[i+1][j])
            q.append(M[i][j-1])
            q.append(M[i][j+1])
          #Fifth step
          while len(q) != 0: #same as saying 'while q is not empty'
            if q[0] == 1:
              M[0] = L
              q.append(M[i-1][j])
              q.append(M[i+1][j])
              q.append(M[i][j-1])
              q.append(M[i][j+1])
          #Sixth step
          L = L + 1
                
  #Seventh step: goes to the beginning of the for-cycle

  return labels
```

Comment: Please fix the code indentation.

Comment: I'm sorry @DavideMadrisan, I think now it's okay

Answer (score 0):

`pyplot.binarize` in its most simple form thresholds an image such that any intensity whose value is beyond a certain threshold is assigned a binary 1 / `True` and a binary 0 / `False` otherwise.  It is actually more sophisticated than this as it uses some image morphology for noise removal as well as use adaptive thresholds to find the most optimal value to separate between foreground and background.  As I see this post as more for validating the connected components algorithm you've created, I'm going to assume that the basic algorithm is fine and the actual algorithm to be out of scope for your needs.

Once you read in the image with matplotlib, it is most likely going to be three channels so you'll need to convert the image into grayscale first, then threshold after.  We can make this more adaptive based on the number of channels that exist.

Therefore, let's define a function to threshold the image for us.  You'll need to play around with the threshold until you get good results.  Also take note that `plt.imread` reads in `float32` values, so the threshold will be defined between `[0-1]`.  We can try 0.5 as a good start:

```py
def binarize(im, threshold=0.5):
    if len(im.shape) == 3:
        gray = 0.299*im[...,0] + 0.587*im[...,1] + 0.114*im[...,2]
    else:
        gray = im
    return (gray >= threshold).astype(np.uint8)
```

This will check if the input image is in RGB.  If it is, convert to grayscale accordingly.  The method to convert from RGB to grayscale uses the [SMPTE Rec. 709 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Luma_coding_in_video_systems).  Once we have the grayscale image, simply return a new image where everything that meets the threshold and beyond gets assigned an integer 1 and everything else is integer 0.  I've converted the result to an integer type because your connected components algorithm assumes a 0/1 labelling.

You can then replace your code with:

```py
    #First step
    Image = plt.imread(image) #reads the image on the argument
    M = binarize(Image) #imbinarize() converts an image to a binary matrix
    (row, column) = np.M.shape #shape of the matrix
```

## Minor Note

In your test code, you are supplying a test image directly whereas your actual code performs an `imread` operation.  `imread` expects a **string** so by specifying the actual array, your code will produce an error.  If you want to accommodate for both an array and a string, you should check to see if the input is a string vs. an array:

```py
    if type(image) is str:
        Image = plt.imread(image) #reads the image on the argument
    else:
        Image = image

    M = binarize(Image) #imbinarize() converts an image to a binary matrix
    (row, column) = np.M.shape #shape of the matrix
```